# Как исправить регулярное выражение оборачивания тегом?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, vue.js

не могу разобраться как сделать чтобы регулярное выражение искало оборачивало в тег только слова которые находятся вне атрибутов тега img и вообще любого тега
это текущий код

```
html = html.replace(new RegExp(localStorage.getItem('selectedText'), 'g'), `<strong class='highlightText'>${localStorage.getItem('selectedText')}</strong>`);
      html = html.replace(/<img.*?src="(.*?)"/g, "<img src=\"https://static.test.co$1\"");
      html = html.replace(/<a(.*?)>(.*?)<\/a>/g, "<a$1>$2<i class=\"icon-external-link\"></i></a>");
```

сейчас эта строчка

```
html = html.replace(new RegExp(localStorage.getItem('selectedText'), 'g'), `<strong class='highlightText'>${localStorage.getItem('selectedText')}</strong>`);
```

оборачивает в тег span не только простые слова на странице но и слова которые находятся в атрибуте src тега img, и это ломает url адрес изображения на странице. нужна помощь в исправлении

Answer (score 0):

```js
html = html.replace(new RegExp(`(?<!img.*?)${localStorage.getItem('selectedText')}(?![^<>]*>)`, 'g'), `<strong class='highlightText'>$&</strong>`);
```